# How can a number triangle come out of this code?

Tags: java, string

I'm a beginner in java and this code was used in a book I'm reading, however I can't seem to figure out how it works.

The code:

```
public class NumberTriangleWhile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 0;
        String output = "";

        while (number < 10) {
        output = output + number;
            System.out.println(output);
            number++;
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
0
01
012
0123
01234
012345
0123456
01234567
012345678
0123456789
```

I don't understand why each number is printed and then somehow stored and reused in the next line, can someone explain this please?

Comment: What do you think `output = output + number;` does? In which order it is execute? How does it behave in each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`output` is a string variable. When you add something to it like this:

```
output = output + number;
```

It does not add the numerical value of the `number`, but instead just joins the number with the original string. For example, if `output` was originally `1` and `number` is `2`, the above line will change `output` to `12`, not `3`.

The loop keeps looping until `number` is 10. In the first iteration, `output` changed from an empty string to `0`. In the second iteration (`number` has now increased to 1), `output` changed to `01` (the original `0` joined with the current value of `number` - 1). In the third iteration, `number` is incremented to 2. `2` is then added to the end of `output` to form `012`. This carries on until number is 10.

The misconception you have might be that you think `output` becomes empty after you print it. ***It does not.*** It will still hold the same value.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I understand now that the numbers are not added together, however I am still a little puzzled as to why the String output = ""; is being used? It is just an empty value? When I replaced "" with "abc" it prints abc at the start of every row, so why can I not just leave it out?

Comment: @Jannis `””` represents an empty string. That’s how Java’s syntax works. Java forces you to initialise every local variable before you use them.

Answer (score 1):

In every step inside `while` loop, `output` added with `number`, in Java adding something with `String` will result in `String` for example:

```
String str = "a" + 2;
```

results in `str="a2";`.

If we start our loop, in first step `number = 0` and `output=""` hence `output = "" + 0` that make `output = "0"` in second run `number=1` hence `output = "0"` `(Old output value) + 1` that make `output = "01"` and so on

Answer (score 0):

The string output is defined outside of the while loop. It can be read from and written to inside of the while loop and its contents will be consistent in the next iteration.

If output would be defined inside of the while loop, for example:

```
while ( number < 10) {
   String output = "";
   output += number;
}
```

then your output would just be (with new line after each number)
    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9

Since the new number is consistent throughout each iteration of the while loop, it is "stored" as you say

Answer (score 0):

Each number is getting printed because its getting concatenated.
When `number=0`,
And you are storing the value of number into the output as:
`Output=output+number`
Then the number which is an integer gets stored as a string in the output
Each time the loop runs the new incremented number gets concatenated with the previous value in the string output.
That's why all numbers are getting printed each time.

make this change in your code and you'll get your output

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     int number=0;
     String output="";
     while(number <10)
     {
         output=output+number;
         System.out.println(output);
         number++;
         output="";
     }
}
```